# How can I find a date that a sum of column reached a certain number?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table for orders (simplified version here):

```
+------+------------+------------+---------+
| id   | customerID | date       | amount  |
+------+------------+------------+---------+
| 1    | 1          | 2019-08-02 | 100     |
| 2    | 1          | 2019-08-24 | 350     |
| 3    | 2          | 2019-09-03 | 250     |
| 4    | 3          | 2019-09-04 | 150     |
etc
+------+------------+-------+--------------+
```

How can I find the date that each customer hit a milestone of $X in total sales (ex you reached gold status on xx/xx/xx)

I am not even sure where to start with this, so any direction would be helpful.

Comment: Be nice if you shared some SQL from taking a stab at it. When I am stuck like this I often go to this resource for ideas on where to start: https://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php

Comment: @ficuscr This is probbaly exactly what I need. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction